# How do i extract the camera extrinsic parameters from homography mapping image points to z=0? (Birdeye view IPM method)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

I have a homography matrix that maps image plane to the world plane z=0.

My first question is that without intrinsic matrix what extrinsic parameters can i extract?

Second, I do have intrinsic matrix, i would also like to know how i can extract all extrinsic parameters having intrinsic matrix. I searched over the net, i used solvepnp, cv2.calibrateCamera and linear algebra methods and all give different answers.
As an example i sample 10000 points and find the mapping through homography and feed it to calibratecamera and my tvecs each time are significantly different.

Now from birdeye view i can see where my camera is based on the cone of visible area. simply by continueing the cone lines. i assume that gives me the camera position and yaw. However i really appreciate a rigourous and robust method for extracting extrinsic parameters from homography to world plane.

Most of the content out there refer to stereo vision and there is no comprehensive answer to this.
I truly appreciate your help.

My linear algebra method:

```
inv_intrinsic = np.linalg.inv(intrinsic)

    # Compute rotation matrix
    r1 = np.dot(inv_intrinsic, homography[:, 0])
    r2 = np.dot(inv_intrinsic, homography[:, 1])
    t = np.dot(inv_intrinsic, homography[:, 2])

    # Normalize r1, r2, and t
    lambda_1 = 1 / np.linalg.norm(r1)
    r1 *= lambda_1
    r2 *= lambda_1
    t *= lambda_1

    # Compute r3 as the cross product of r1 and r2
    r3 = np.cross(r1, r2)

    # Build rotation and translation matrix
    Rt = np.c_[r1, r2, r3, t]
    camera_position = -np.dot(Rt[:3, :3].T, Rt[:3, 3])
```

Then i used solvepnp and calibratecamera and also Polar function. The polar function usage is as following

```
normalized_homography = inv_intrinsic @ homography
R, T = polar(normalized_homography)
t = T[:, 2]
```

Update: I have already calibrated the camera using intrinisic matrix. The intrinsic that i am using is the new camera intrinsic after undistortion.

Comment: You cannot find the camera if you only know points lying on the same plane. What is your goal exactly ?

Comment: I need to find the position of the camera on the bird-eye view map. Even if i cant find the height of the camera that would be fine. mostly i need to find the projection matrix in a way that i can backproject a point on image plane to a line on the birdeye view map. Thats my ultimate objective. any suggestion that allows me to do such would be great. Thanks

Comment: Also from what i know, cv2.calibrateCamera gets point on the checkerboard and returns relative rotation and translation of the checkerboard with respect to cam. Then i have mimicked the same process by feeding the position of bev maps and the corresponding points on image plane with 10000 points but at each try i get different answers. Maybe points above vanishing line distrupt the process i am not sure. Very confused

Comment: revcs and tvecs from calibrateCamera are camera pose, rvec and tvec from somvePnp are object pose. When using ground point sanples from honography and calibrateCamera, make sure to fix all the intrinsics and coefficients.

Comment: `calibrateCamera` docs state about the rvec/tvec pair: "performs a change of basis from object coordinate space to camera coordinate space. Due to its duality, this tuple is equivalent to the position of the calibration pattern with respect to the camera coordinate space." that means those too represent the board/pattern pose, not the camera pose. -- I think cC and sPnP pose results should agree, given the same data, upto numerical differences and possibly lens distortion